# Why does this bluebird pg code hang?

Tags: node.js, bluebird, node-postgres

I'm trying to wrap my head around bluebird Promises, and going through some examples in the documentation.  My current code is based on [this example](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#disposerfunction-disposer---disposer):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var pg = Promise.promisifyAll(require('pg'));
var using = Promise.using;

function getConnection(string) {
    var close;
    return pg.connectAsync(string).spread(function(client, done) {
        close = done;
        return client;
    }).disposer(function() {
        console.log('In disposer');
        try {
            if (close) close();
        } catch(e) {};
    });
};

using(getConnection('/var/run/postgresql dc'), function(conn) {
    console.log('Got a connection');
    return conn.queryAsync('SELECT 1');
})
.then(function(rows) {
    console.log('Retrieved %s row(s)',rows.rowCount);
});
```

The output is as expected:

```
Got a connection
In disposer
Retrieved 1 row(s)
```

However, the program never terminates. What's the hang-up (pun intended)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, it appears the bluebird example code is broken.  The proper code for `getConnection()` should be:

```
function getConnection(string) {
    var close;
    return pg.connectAsync(string).spread(function(client, done) {
        close = done;
        return client;
    }).disposer(function(client) {
        console.log('In disposer');
        try {
            if (close) close(client);
        } catch(e) {};
    });
};
```

Specifically, `done()` must be called on the `client` object, which the disposer function receives as its first argument (although it is ignored in the example).